# Empty space between two &

Tags: regular-expression, filetype-tex, original-vim

I want to empty inner columns in a latex table, ie all the words between 2 &. How I can do it ?
I have tried quite a few formulas like

```
s/&*&/\& \&/gc
```

but I just can't find the right pattern to match.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: could you provide an example? Original text vs Result text?

Comment: You need an atom to repeat with `*`, eg, `[^&]*`

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
s/&\zs.\{-}\ze&/ /gc
```

Disassembled:

- `&` is the literal ampersand
- `\zs` sets the start of the match
- `.\{-}` matches any characters - but as *few* as possible
- `\ze` sets the end of the match
- `&` is the literal ampersand

There are two special things here=

First `\zs...\ze`: The part between them are the matched text, the ampersand before and after are just "anchors". This is important, as otherwise the matches would overlap like:

```
 &  This Stuff   &  Other Stuff  &
 |-- 1st match --|
                 |-- 2nd match --|
```

Second `.\{-}`: The dot matches any character and the `\{-}` defines zero or more matches, but as few as possible. The next character in the match is a `&`. So it matches zero or more chars until it finds a ampersand.

The replacement is just a simple whitespace, as we just replace the part between the ampersands.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for the solution and the detailed explanations.